# Set host firewall so VMs obtain dynamic IP from dnsmasq

Tags: centos, iptables, kvm-virtualization, dnsmasq, libvirt

Virtual machines (KVM/libvirt) fail to obtain a dynamic IP address from the libvirt-launched dnsmasq running on a CentOS host when the firewall is running. When I turn off the firewall (CSF), the virtual machine obtains an IP. For those who have encountered similar, what worked for you?

I have tried custom iptables rules (INPUT OUTPUT and FORWARD) in csfpost.sh.

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT  -j ACCEPT -s $SUBNET_PRIVATE -i $IF_TUN_0  
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -s $SUBNET_PRIVATE -o $IF_TUN_0  
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i $IF_TUN_0 -o $IF_ETH_0 -j ACCEPT  
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i $IF_ETH_0 -o $IF_TUN_0 -j ACCEPT
```

I have tried entries in csf.allow.

```
#allow dnsmasq to serve dynamic IPs to virtual machines on local subnet 
tcp:in:d=53:s=10.x.y.0/24 
udp:in:d=53:s=10.x.y.0/24 
tcp:out:d=53:s=10.x.y.0/24 
udp:out:d=53:s=10.x.y.0/24
```

What essential step(s) have I overlooked?

Comment: Configuration of UDP port ranges used by dnsmasq are missing in the origninal post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After determining how to open up everything...

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT  -j ACCEPT -p all -s 0/0 -i $IF_TUN_0
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -p all -s 0/0 -o $IF_TUN_0
```

The clue came from /var/log/messages. Ports 67 and 68 were blocked.

```
# allow broadcasted dhcp requests, IP is unknown hence all zero'd
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT  -j ACCEPT -p udp -d 0/0 -i $IF_TUN_0 --dport 67 --sport 68
# allow dhcp renewal requests, the IP is known at this point
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT  -j ACCEPT -p udp -d $IP_PRIVATE_HOST -i $IF_TUN_0 --dport 68 --sport 67

# allow dhcp acks
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT  -j ACCEPT -p udp -s $IP_PRIVATE_HOST -o $IF_TUN_0 --dport 68 --sport 67
# allow dhcp renewal response
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT  -j ACCEPT -p udp -s $IP_PRIVATE_HOST -o $IF_TUN_0 --dport 67 --sport 68
```